# Returning prvalues from funtion

Tags: c++, c++17

As of C++17, copy elision is mandatory, and it has changed how prvalues work. Now, when returning a temporary (I know its not really a temporary, just an initializer), the initializer is passed up the call chain and used to initialize the object that is used to store the result of function.

My question is, how can an initializer be passed up the function call chain? Or am I wrong about how this works?

For example:

```
struct Foo
{
  // some impl...
}

Foo Bar()
{
  return Foo{}; // temporary not constructed, prvalue passed up
}

int main()
{
  Foo foo = Bar(); // equivalent to Foo foo; 
}
```

Comment: @user10605163 added

Comment: The initializer is `Foo{}`, being passed up to `Foo foo`.

Comment: Not really sure what kind of answer you are looking for. From the perspective of `c++`, all you really need to know is that it's equivalent. No copying or moving needed. If you are interested in compiler implementation you most likely need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Hm. I'm not exactly sure how to phrase my question then. I'll try to phrase it in a more broad sense.

Comment: @KrystianS: Your question really seems to be "how does copy elision work". That is, how it gets implemented at the compiler level.

Comment: Yes, your question is really about copy elision. Very roughly for a typical case, space is reserved on the caller's stack for in-place construction of the return value before the function call. The address of this space is passed implicitly to the function. The function then constructs the return value in the caller's stack space using that address. Does this make sense?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Ok, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The trick is in the calling convention.

Return values are in essence passed as pointers to where the function wants the return value constructed.

This is passed all the way up to the inner most function call, and the prvalue there directly constructs the result in the end object location.

When guarenteed elision was being added, the standard committee double checked that every major compiler was already using such a calling convention and no technical barrier or ABI break would occur.

The above only contains small lies, but as a what-if story makes the result plausible, and in most ways is true.

The important lie is that what happens in the abstract machine the C++ standard is described using, there is no "pointer to return object location" passed; rather, the prvalue must *somehow* construct the end-object.  The *how* is immaterial.

So whenever the pointer isn't there, the compiler can still construct the object as-if the pointer was there.  (For example, returning certain kinds of objects in registers; for trivially copyable aggregate types whose address is not taken, when (and sometimes if) it takes its final location is not observable).

Comment: The exciting part is that the lifetime of the object begins when the prvalue is “constructed” rather than when the result object is initialized (which is after many relevant intervening variables may have been destroyed).